# Adding authentication based on API key and API secret to APIs in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am working on a Spring Boot application where existing user authentication is based on Oauth2 with 2FA. Now, I would like to call the APIs in my application from the third-party client as well, say from another service.

Basically, I would like to develop one auth API, where on providing a valid client name, valid API key, and API secret, the client will get an auth token, which will be valid for say 1 hour. Then this auth token can be passed in all successive API invocation until the token gets expired.

I found a few articles here:

a. [Securing Spring Boot API with API key and secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446708/securing-spring-boot-api-with-api-key-and-secret)

b. [How to secure spring Boot API with API key and secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57135288/how-to-secure-spring-boot-api-with-api-key-and-secret)

c. [how to implement api key secure in spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68886213/how-to-implement-api-key-secure-in-spring-boot)

d. [How to config multiple level authentication for spring boot RESTful web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54134252/how-to-config-multiple-level-authentication-for-spring-boot-restful-web-service)

But, I am not getting any concrete idea regarding, how to achieve this.

Could you please suggest how can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: for starters, better for you to learn the implementation of OAuth security with spring boot. Then you can go for 2FA and other stuff after you figure out the basics. I would suggest you to look into some tutorials.. there are bunch of tutorials in youtube as well.

Comment: @Natsu Sorry for the confusion. Actually, in my application, the authentication based on 2FA is already there. In addition to this, I would like to add API authentication based on API key and API secret as I mentioned in the OP.